# How to implement fgets using low-level I/O?

Tags: c, unix, io, architecture, operating-system

```
char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream)
```

I understand this two are very different. fgets works with a FILE *, read works with a file descriptor. fgets reads until newline, read reads how much you tell it to. Is it possible to implement fgets, or see the system code for fgets?

Comment: Q: _Is it possible to implement fgets, or see the system code for fgets?_ A: yes it is possible, almost the whole C CRT library is written in C. Q: _Is it possible to see the system code for fgets_? A: yes, it is. Just google "fgets source code"  (no joke), there are many implementations, more or less every platform has it's own.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: For what it's worth, it's *not possible* to implement the C standard library entirely in C. Large parts can be, though.

Comment: @R.. right, I edited the comment.

Answer (score 2):

`fgets` can be implemented efficiently only on top of stdio buffering; otherwise, since there is no underlying variant of `read` that stops at the first newline, you would have to repeatedly call `read` with a requested length of 1.

If you are interested in reading the source for some implementations, here is glibc's:

- https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/iofgets.c
- https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/iogetline.c

and here is musl's:

- https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/stdio/fgets.c